# Error Message Not Appearing in Vue and Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vee-validate

I'm using Vuetify and Vee-Validate in my VueApp.

I tried to use `<span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>` and it appears but when i tried to `:error-messages="errors[0]"` it doesnt appear.

```
                  <ValidationProvider rules="required|email" name="Username" v-slot="{ errors }">
                    <v-text-field
                      label="Username"
                      v-model="form.username"
                      type="email"
                      outlined
                      hide-details
                      :error-messages="errors[0]"
                    ></v-text-field>
                      <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                  </ValidationProvider>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `hide-details` prop is hiding the part of the component that shows the error messages. Try `hide-details="auto"`, which will hide it by default, but show when there are errors/hints.

Comment: Thanks bro, I'm new to Vue. I found this fix after 5hours